# Parsing JSON in java / Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have this format of code. Can anyone help me how can I read the array? I need to read contacts array.

```
 {
  "success": true,
  "contacts": [
  {
  "username": "ceema",
  "profile": {
    "name": "Ceema S",
    "email": "ceemas@gmail.com",
    "address": "No 143, gangaeyam, Maikkad P O, Kerala",
    "phone": {
      "mobile": "3333",
      "home": "2222",
      "office": "6666"
    }
  }
},
{
  "username": "hari",
  "profile": {
    "name": "Harikrishnan V S",
    "email": "harikriii@gmail.com",
    "address": "No 143, harihome, Maikkad P O, Kerala",
    "phone": {
      "mobile": "3333",
      "home": "2222",
      "office": "6666"
    }
  }
},
{
  "username": "pranav",
  "profile": {
    "name": "Pranav Mohan",
    "email": "pranavmohan@gmail.com",
    "address": "No 143, harihome, Maikkad P O, Kerala",
    "phone": {
      "mobile": "3333",
      "home": "2222",
      "office": "6666"
    }
  }
}
]
}
```

**I tried  this :**

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    //String id = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    //String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);
```

This **jsonstr** is json response from the site.
I need to read the nested contacts and populate it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This jsonstr is json response from the site. I need to read the nested
>   contacts and populate it to

you got it almost right. The objects you are looking for are inside profile

```
JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject profile = c.getJSONObject("profile");
```

and use `profile` instead of `c`, to look of name, phone and the others

Comment: I was trying to get on c object only so was getting the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check this link a very simple way to parse json
http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to get POJO class from json using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

You will get all the required classes to convert this json into POJO class,
and later you can use Gson library from google to convert json into Object and the other way around.

Think of this, if you get a Contact class as parent class then you can easily use fromjson method from Gson.

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
Contact contact = gson.fromJson(json_string, Contact.class);
```

Now you can easily use this class for further use.
Hope this helps.